# cannnot read property of Undefined Node Js Post request

Tags: node.js, postman

I Send post request with body as JSON object but could not read values of req.body (it prints undefined).
validate() is a custom function to vlidate the JSON data received.

issue faced: cannot read value of undefined.

```js
router.post('/', async (req,res)=>{
    const error = validate(req.body);

    if(error) res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

    let user = await User.findOne({email : req.body.email});

    if(user) res.status(400).send("user already exists");

    user = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        phone: req.body.phone,
        password: req.body.password
    });

    const result = await user.save();
    res.send(result);
});
```

Comment: 1. When you print the `req.body` at first line is it still produce `undefined`?
2. Are there any middlewares? 3. Please add the request (if from GUI like postman - export as curl) and the response

Comment: Are you using express js ? If so you need to use the **body-parser** .